# C# как проверить все установленные браузеры

Tags: c#, windows, браузер

Подскажите как на C# можно получить название и путь до .exe файла(в Windows) всех установленных браузеров? В конечном счёте, я хочу их запускать.

Понимаю, что можно посмотреть их в папке, но мне кажется это не чистый подход

Comment: Браузеры ничем не отличаются от обычных приложений, нет каких либо отметок о том, является ли приложение браузером или не браузером. Соответственно, понятия "все установленные браузеры" технически не существует

Comment: @andreymal понял, спасибо, тогда не подскажите как получить все установленные приложения, но искать не в одной папке, а посмотреть везде(понятно относительно везде)

Comment: в смысле, найти все exe файлики на компьютере? Браузер может быть просто файликом в папке лежать жеж, в портативном виде.

Comment: @tym32167 однако попадает ли такой файлик под понятие "установленный" - сложный вопрос

Comment: @andreymal вообще-то не смотря на то, что технически браузер это такая же программа как и все остальные, все же список браузеров получить вполне возможно. Просто потому, что браузеры в виндовсе регистрируют себя как браузер. И появляются в списке "стандартных программ для серфинга в интернете". Так было и в виндовс ХР и это же особенно актуально для виндовс 10 и 11, где стандартный браузер можно выбрать только с этого специфического меню "форточки". https://remontka.pro/images/select-default-browser-windows-10-settings.png

Comment: @Andrew я ждал этот комментарий) Только вот, во-первых, не все браузеры себя регистрируют, а во-вторых, ничто не мешает зарегистрироваться другой программе, не являющейся браузером

Comment: Я ждал этот комментарий. Только как часто за свою жизнь ты встречал ситуации когда какая-то иная программа регистрировала себя как браузер или что бы браузер себя не регистрировал в этом списке себя как браузер?) Лично я за 31 год жизни такого не видел ни разу. Потому что у 99,99% на компьютере стоит не какая-то редкостная вундервафля, а минимум один из 5 наипопулярнейших браузеров. Да и этот список вполне себе подпадает под запрос artemgh.

Comment: @Andrew ну что ж, поздравляю с первым разом в вашей жизни — http://netsurf-browser.org/

Comment: Прекрасно. Встречу пользователя с этим на копьютере - тогда и будет первый раз. А пока что им вряд ли пользуются хотя бы 0,01% пользователей))) И это можно считать лютым исключением которым можно пренебречь.

Comment: @Andrew я пользуюсь, проверяю в нём вёрстку своих сайтов и регулярно пишу новости о новых версиях на ЛОРе :)

Comment: @Andrew пренебрегая исключениями, вы нарушаете указанное в вопросе условие «всех установленных»

Comment: Учитывая вероятность такого исключения - этим и вправду можно пренебречь)

Comment: Мне нравится вариант @Andrew не спорю, что andreymal прав. Но в моём случае, я буду просить пользователя при запуске выбрать один из браузеров, поэтому он сам будет решать какой браузер использовать, мне главное дать ему варианты, разумеется оставлю возможность, самому указать путь

Comment: @Andrew не подскажите как мне реализовать такой вариант?

Comment: не, гугли на англоязычном SO

Comment: @Andrew ок, в любом случае, спасибо